# Array - Convert date format for all Date fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have following array, there are some fields like `dateofbirth` in which I need to remove the time and change the format to `MM-DD-YYYY`.

```
var records = [
    {
        "recordno":"000001",
        "firstname":"Bo",
        "middlename":"G",
        "lastname":"Dallas",
        "gender":"male",
        "dateofbirth":"2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "dateofdeath":null,
        "_id":"538c701c84ee56601f000063",
    },
    {
        "recordno":"000001",
        "firstname":"Bo",
        "middlename":"G",
        "lastname":"Dallas",
        "gender":"male",
        "dateofbirth":"2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "dateofdeath":null,
        "_id":"538c701c84ee56601f000067",
    },
];
```

How to convert date format in an array for all fields which have `Date` type as data type?

Answer (score 1):

Are the dates in your array date objects? Do you want to convert them to strings? Then maybe this will work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
    var birthDate = new Date(records[i].dateofbirth);

    var newBirthDateString = ('0' + birthDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-'
                + ('0' + (birthDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-'
                + birthDate.getFullYear();
    records[i].dateofbirth = newBirthDateString;

    if (records[i].dateofdeath !== null) {
        var deathDate = new Date(records[i].dateofdeath);

        var newDeathDateString = ('0' + deathDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-'
                + ('0' + (deathDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-'
                + deathDate.getFullYear();
        records[i].dateofdeath = newDeathDateString;
    }    
}
```

Comment: When i use this code in my .js, it gives me syntax errors

Comment: I tried it, it formats dateofbirth but not dateofdeath.

Comment: Edited to include dateofdeath.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code. Hope this help you!

```
var records = [
    {
        "recordno":"RF-000001",
        "firstname":"Bo",
        "middlename":"G",
        "lastname":"Dallas",
        "gender":"male",
        "dateofbirth":"2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "dateofdeath":null,
        "_id":"538c701c84ee56601f000063",
    },
    {
        "recordno":"RF-000001",
        "firstname":"Bo",
        "middlename":"G",
        "lastname":"Dallas",
        "gender":"male",
        "dateofbirth":"2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "dateofdeath":null,
        "_id":"538c701c84ee56601f000067",
    },
];

for(var i=0;i<records.length;i++){
    if(records[i].dateofbirth){
        var splitDateTime = records[i].dateofbirth.split("T");
        var splitDate = splitDateTime[0].split("-");
        records[i].dateofbirth = splitDate[1] +"-"+ splitDate[2] +"-"+ splitDate[0];
    }
}
```

JSFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/YdBCq/1/

**Updated:**

It converts based on date field. Hope this help you!

```
for(var i=0;i<records.length;i++){
    for( var attrName in records[i]){
        if(records[i][attrName].indexOf("T") == 10){
             var splitDateTime = records[i][attrName].split("T");
             var splitDate = splitDateTime[0].split("-");
             records[i][attrName] = splitDate[1] +"-"+ splitDate[2] +"-"+ splitDate[0];
        }

    }
}
```

JSFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/YdBCq/3/

Comment: This is working, but i have 2 more date fields in my Array..so is there any shortcut..